# Create JSON object in Java8 using com.google.code.gson

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0, java-8, gson

I am trying to create a JSON Object using `com.google.code.jso` in JAVA 8. I have a list of objects and i am iterating through them. The object is as:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name, status, cause, id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getCause() {
        return cause;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

I have a list of above objects and i am trying to convert them to JSON using the below (the relevant code):

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
for (MyObject obj : objectLists){
            status.add(obj.getId(),
                    new JsonObject()
                            .add("Name: ", obj.getName())
                            .add("Status: ", obj.getStatus())
                            .add("Cause: ", obj.getCause())
            );
        }
```

I was hoping to get a JSON of the following form:

```
{

  "0 (this is the id i get from myObject.getId())": {
    "name": The name i get from myObject.getName(),
    "Status": The status from myobject.getStatus(),
    "cause": The status from myobject.getCause()
  },
 "1": {
    "name": "myname",
    "Status": "mystatus",
    "cause": "cause"
  }
}
```

So I have 2 question.

1. I am getting an error in creating the Json object. `Wrong 2nd
   argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required:
   'com.google.gson.JsonElement'` I understand that i have to change
   the second parameter but i could not find in the docs how to do
   that.
2. How can i pretty print this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You used wrong method:
`JsonObject.addProperty()`, not `JsonObject.add()`

`JsonObject.add(String, JsonElement)` - adds nested json element to your object:

```
{
    "root": {
        "nested": {}
    }
}
```

`JsonObject.addProperty(String, String)` - adds property to your object (it may be any primitive or String):

```
{
    "root": {
        "property": "some string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using this instead.

```
Gson.toJson(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your strings in [`JsonPrimitive`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html) objects, for example:

```
new JsonObject().add("Name: ", new JsonPrimitive(obj.getName()));
```

To enable pretty printing, you have to use [`GsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
```

Comment: `add` is `void` so you cannot chain the method invocations. Also you may consider using `jObj.addProperty("Name", obj.getName());` directly instead of explicitly wrapping the `String` in a `JsonPrimitive`.

Comment: how do i chain them then?

Comment: @AlexisC. By doing  `status.addProperty("name",obj.getName()) ` i am able to get rid of the 1st error but i am not able to understand how to chain them.

Comment: @200ok You can't chain them, as `add` / `addProperty` are `void` methods.

Comment: @AlexisC. In Java 6, i think, there was something called as `json.put` which was able to chain. Pardon me if i am wrong. So how do i get the desired json (i have show that in the question) in this case? Any pointers?

Comment: @200ok It's irrelevant to the version of Java you are using, but rather the version of the Gson API you are using. I don't understand why you are worried about chaining the methods. Create an instance of a `JsonObject`, store it in a variable and call `addProperty` on that instance, with multiple statements.